# Custom subscript in Java

Tags: java, swift

In Apple's programming language Swift, you can use subscript as you do in arrays for your own class.
For example a class in Swift could look like this:

```
class MyNumber {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Int {
        return value * i
    }
}
```

This class only has a getter subscript but you could do a setter subscript, too. Anyway when doing this:

```
let number = MyNumber(value: 15)
println(number[3])
```

it produces the output 45.

Is it possible to write such classes using subscript in Java as well? Of course, I could simply use a method with a parameter but I wanted to know if this is possible.
Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: Nope, not possible. There is no operator overloading in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Setting something equal to `Class()` in Java is creating a new instantiation of that object. Just do something like this:

```
var = new MyNumber(15)
var.multiply(3)
```

and in your `MyNumber` class code, change `subscript` to `multiply` for clarity. That will work the same.

A shorthand version of the same principle is

```
System.out.println(new MyNumber(15).multiply(3));
```